# strong type model in view in agularjs application

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

is it possible to have strong type model in view , i mean html file in angular application ?

so when i am doing data binding in template i get Intellisense for my model properties.

**JS**

```
$scope.person = {
     name: "Arash",
     lastName: "Ghoreyshi"
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>{{person .}} </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

so when i type {{person .}} i get intellisense for person properties.
i am using visual studio 2015

Comment: I think you are taking about the plug in installation please refer this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/ you may get some idea out of it

Comment: this works in js file , i already installed it . i want strong type model in template( html file ).

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190300/html-angular-intellisense-in-visualstudio (this is hack I didn't tried this I came across this post thought of sharing you)

Comment: you can also have a look on this link https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/02/28/angularjs-support-for-resharper/ too